# MPMoviePlayerViewController Finished the App returns Landscape

Tags: iphone

I have a MPMoviePlayerViewController, while the video plays fine if the video is in landscape, and when it finished the app turns to landscape. After video finished I want the App to remain portrait.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
        //[moviePlayer shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:(moviePlayer.moviePlayer)];
        [self  presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
        [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override your view controller's `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to return YES only for portrait.